# ERROR/Web Console: Uncaught Error: Too much time spent in unload handler

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When I load a url via WebView, I sometimes receive a flood of numerous messages like this:

```
10-19 19:18:38.056: ERROR/Web Console(6524): 
Uncaught Error: Too much time spent in unload handler. at v8/DateExtension:1
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: did you solved this issue if yes then please provide me the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be defined in DateExtension.cpp, in webkit. It's a C++ exception that is thrown if a JS hook (inserted into Date.getTime, if enableSleepDetection(true) is set) is called more than 1000 times.

You might want to fetch the Android source code to look into it more. There's no documentation on the file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. After some investigating I have solved this issue.
Maybe this code will help you:

```
        {
            webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.transcationwebview);
                progressdialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "",
                        mContext.getString(R.string.please_wait));
                progressdialog.setCancelable(true);
                progressdialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        webView.stopLoading();
                        // webView.clearView();

                    }
                });



                webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeClient());
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(
                        WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
                webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // view.loadUrl(url);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                        if (progressdialog != null && progressdialog.isShowing()) {
                            progressdialog.dismiss();
                        } 

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                            String description, String failingUrl) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    }
                });
                webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
                webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
                webView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl(url);
}
    public class MyChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                try {

                    if (progressdialog.isShowing()) {
                        progressdialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading)
                                + newProgress + " %");

                    } else {
                        /*
                         * webView.stopLoading(); webView.clearView();
                         */
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```